# Installing pygame module in anaconda mac

Tags: python, pygame, anaconda

I have [Anaconda](http://www.continuum.io/) installed on my mac. And it has messed with my pygame module.

I tried following this [tutorial](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=foreword&lang=en#section_0_1_2) and replacing `pip3 install pygame` with `conda install pygame`. I have tried `conda install pip` and then `pip install pygame` yet i get the following error:

```
Collecting pygame
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pygame
  Some externally hosted files were ignored as access to them may be unreliable (use --allow-external pygame to allow).
  No distributions at all found for pygame
```

(ideas i got from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25467595/unable-to-pip-install-packages-in-anaconda))

Using the "pip install pygame" worked before i did the "conda install pip" however my default python is now the anaconda one and no longer accesses pygame. Using `which pip` gives `/Users/jensdonlin/anaconda/bin/pip`

Does anyone have some suggestions that would allow anaconda's version of python3 to access pygame?

Perhaps the answer involves `use --allow-external pygame to allow` but im not really sure how to use that.

Comment: In struggling with this problem I have gotten a better handle of pip. And so I have decided to deleted anaconda and simple use pip to install all my modules.

Comment: It's unfair to blame `anaconda` here. Have you read the docs how to install `pygame` on a mac? There are instructions on their website: http://pygame.org/wiki/macintosh

Comment: I am not blaming anyone, I think anaconda is awesome. I am fairly new to programming and its something I dont understand how to do. I know how to install pygame with python 3. but I am remain unsure how to install it into the anaconda version of python. The instructions on pygame.org won't install pygame into anaconda. even if i change `pip3` to `conda`. So I've decided to use what I know that works.

Comment: I would suggest trying `conda install pip`. Then edit your question and add the output of `which -a pip`.

Comment: I tried conda install pip too unfortunately that didnt work either.
I also asked this question on the continuum google group and got some really helpful feedback and reasons why it won't work. Should anyone have a similar issue.https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/anaconda/-37R-DwkRVg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that the pygame developers have not uploaded pygame to PyPI. So to install it, you will have to download it and pip install the downloaded source, as described in the tutorial you linked. You can do this within the Anaconda Python. Note that in the Anaconda Python, even if it is Python 3, pip is just called `pip`, not `pip3`.

Answer (score 12):

After 2 days of messing around with macports and homebrew with no joy, the instructions [here](http://www.srmathias.com/?p=886) worked for me using Anaconda Python 2.7.10 on a mac. Echoing them here in case the linked site ever disappears!

First open up terminal and enter these two lines:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
brew install sdl sdl_ttf sdl_image sdl_mixer portmidi
```

If you don't have binstar installed type:

```
conda install binstar
```

At this point it might tell you that *The 'binstar' conda package has been renamed to 'anaconda-client'* and that you have to type this instead:

```
conda install anaconda-client
```

Just do whatever it tells you to. Then finally, type:

```
conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/quasiben pygame
```

and hopefully you're done!

Answer (score 0):

i've tried many permutations of pip. the problem is i wasn't specifying the file path i was trying `pip install pygame`. I have now successfully installed pygame by following the tutorial I gave above and using: `pip install /Users/YOURNAME/Downloads/pygame`