# python: spyder, anaconda and pygame

Tags: python, pygame, anaconda, spyder

I have installed anaconda on my on Mac OS(10.9.2), but it's often very slow to open the launcher. Sometimes I can solve it with

```
conda install -f launcher
```

anyone know what's the reason for this.

Therefore,I want to use spyder directly, I have installed spyder and want to change python interpreter path to anaconda, how I can set the directory information there in Preferences > Console > Advanced Settings > Python executable? (the anaconda is installed under applications).

In addition, if I can open anaconda, how I can install **pygame** on it? Thanks!

Comment: *"why python hasn't [sic] have a IDE that is as convenient as Rstudio for R"* - why do you think that? There are many Python IDEs out there, with a range of feature sets. The rest of the question appears to be a request for help configuring your environment - if you break it down into smaller steps, you will find all of them are solved elsewhere on SO.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Spyder is the IDE that I think is close to Rstudio, do you have any better suggestions? In addition, can you show me the link where I can find the answers, I have searched, but failed to find the answer on OS that works for the questions that I am interested in.

Comment: Recommendations are off-topic here. You can find the answers via http://stackoverflow.com/search

Comment: As I've explained, I have tried and can't find the corresponding answer. If you know what the answer is, can you show me the link you noticed,or answer the question directly, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use spyder without using the launcher app, you can open a terminal and move to your anaconda directory. The command 'spyder' will open the IDE.

To change what version of python spyder uses, follow to  Preferences > Console > Advanced Settings > Python executable, and change it to the location of anaconda python,

```
/Users/.../.../anaconda/bin/python
```

For pygame, check this out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29137369/installing-pygame-module-in-anaconda-mac).

Comment: cool, have solved my problem! In term of the pygame installment, I used the last solution of the link you refer to: http://92.42.51.245.cancer.iwanslphotography.com/nph-p.cgi/20/http/stackoverflow.com/questions/29137369/installing-pygame-module-in-anaconda-mac=3frq=3d1

Comment: Although I can successfully import pygame in anaconda, but      `pygame.font.get_fonts()` and `pygame.font.get_default_font()` doesn't work. error suggests image not found.