# (Pip) install googleads in Anaconda

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

I'm using Anaconda on Windows 10. Some packages aren't available to conda install, so I resort to pip installing within Anaconda. Recently I've encountered a number that I've been unable to install in the root environment, but let's take googleads as an example. I've tried both:

```
pip install googleads
pip install git+git://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib
```

from the conda terminal and they both give me the same error - pasted below. I've found that I *can* install it in a virtual environment, but not the root environment. Does anyone know how to fix this?

I've tried adding this line to the end of bash_profile:

```
export PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV=false
```

as suggested here: [Unable to pip install packages in Anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25467595/unable-to-pip-install-packages-in-anaconda) but it hasn't made any difference.

OK, here comes the error message:

```
Collecting googleads
Using cached 
https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/55/5b/397c2ca6ffe116732261d6bd74be9db91f1b1a65916f8525be9a7dfcc3dc/googleads-12.2.0.tar.gz
Collecting google-auth<2.0.0,>=1.0.0 (from googleads)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/53/06/6e6d5bfa4d23ee40efd772d6b681a7afecd859a9176e564b8c329382370f/google_auth-1.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting google-auth-oauthlib<1.0.0,>=0.0.1 (from googleads)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/46/df/d1f94ee2cffe5a83721f262efe51f3b2dcdd3b616caf007b8490e824c550/google_auth_oauthlib-0.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2015.7 in c:\users\tomwagstaff\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from googleads) (2018.4)
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\TomWagstaff\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\basecommand.py", line 228, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\TomWagstaff\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 291, in run
    resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
  File "C:\Users\TomWagstaff\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolve.py", line 103, in resolve
    self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)
  File "C:\Users\TomWagstaff\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolve.py", line 262, in _resolve_one
    check_dist_requires_python(dist)
  File "C:\Users\TomWagstaff\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\packaging.py", line 46, in check_dist_requires_python
    feed_parser.feed(metadata)
  File "C:\Users\TomWagstaff\Anaconda3\lib\email\feedparser.py", line 175, in feed
    self._input.push(data)
  File "C:\Users\TomWagstaff\Anaconda3\lib\email\feedparser.py", line 103, in push
    self._partial.write(data)
TypeError: string argument expected, got 'NoneType'
```